# Youtube -- Certain Videos not shown / not displayed/ omitted from various Channels

Tags: youtube

What measures to take to show all, othesise omitted vioes from beung displayed.
I have noticed this on various channels, on two that I watch regularly so far.

Here's one example of video existing already ..
https://ibb.co/zrkDLgS

.. & the Channel's content displayed, with the video specified in the above-linked screenshot obviously missing!
https://ibb.co/C22KsH8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed [the channel `LIVE` tab](https://www.youtube.com/@PBDPodcast/streams) that references this video, as it's a livestream.
[image: channel LIVE tab]